# How solve problem with dependencies testing NestJS including Mongoose and Cache?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to test Controllers of my App in NestJS using implemented Jest framework. And the problem is that my App has dependencies with MongoDB and CacheService which included in Nest but still needs implementation.

So here's my controller I want to test:

**calculator.controller.ts**

```
@Controller('/calculator')
export class CalculatorController {
  constructor(
    @Inject(HISTORY_SERVICE)
    private historyService: HistoryService,
    @Inject(CACHE_SERVICE)
    private readonly cacheService: CacheService,
  ) {}
  @Get()
  getResult(
    @Query() expressionDto: ExpressionDto,
  ): Promise<CalculationResultDto> {
    const { expression } = expressionDto;
    const response = this.cacheService
      .checkInCache(expression)
      .then((result) => {
        const dto = { result: `${result}`, expression };
        const historyItem = this.historyService.create(dto);
        return historyItem;
      });
    return response;
  }
}
```

As you see I don't use CalculatorService in this Controller because the algorithm of the calculator is as follows. CalculatorController gets the request in the form of an expression for counting. The expression is passed to the CacheService. The expression is checked in the cache, and if it is not there, then the CalculatorService is called from CacheService and the result is returned to the CalculatorController. Next, the HistoryService is called, which is responsible for storing the calculation results in the database. This is necessary in order to send the user to the client the result of the calculation of the expression in the correct form. The database adds an ID and all that.

At the end of all actions, the result is sent to the client.

Now let's take a look at the tests.

**calculator.controller.spec.ts**

```
jest.mock('../calculator.service.ts');

let calculatorController: CalculatorController;
let calculatorService: CalculatorService;

beforeEach(async () => {
  const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [HistoryModule],
    controllers: [CalculatorController],

    providers: [
      { useClass: CalculatorService, provide: CALCULATOR_SERVICE },
      {
        useClass: ExpressionCounterService,
        provide: EXPRESSION_COUNTER_SERVICE,
      },
      {
        useClass: RegExCreatorService,
        provide: REGEXP_CREATOR_SERVICE_INTERFACE,
      },
      { useClass: CacheService, provide: CACHE_SERVICE },
      { useClass: HistoryService, provide: HISTORY_SERVICE },
    ],
  }).compile();
  calculatorController =
    moduleRef.get<CalculatorController>(CalculatorController);
  calculatorService = moduleRef.get<CalculatorService>(CalculatorService);
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

describe('getResult', () => {
  describe('when getResult is called', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
      await calculatorController.getResult(calculatorStub().request);
    });
    test('then it should call calculatorService', () => {
      expect(calculatorService.getResult).toBeCalledWith(
        calculatorStub().request.expression,
      );
    });
  });
});
```

The **Error** is

```
 Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CacheService (?, CALCULATOR_SERVICE). Please make sure that the argument CACHE_MANAGER at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.
```

I completely imitated the real Calculator Module, but even so it doesn't work. Here is my Calculator Module as an example.

**calculator.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [HistoryModule],
  controllers: [CalculatorController],
  providers: [
    { useClass: CalculatorService, provide: CALCULATOR_SERVICE },
    { useClass: ExpressionCounterService, provide: EXPRESSION_COUNTER_SERVICE },
    {
      useClass: RegExCreatorService,
      provide: REGEXP_CREATOR_SERVICE_INTERFACE,
    },
    { useClass: CacheService, provide: CACHE_SERVICE },
    { useClass: HistoryService, provide: HISTORY_SERVICE },
  ],
})
export class CalculatorModule {}
```

I would be very grateful if one of you could help me figure out the problem. Just in case, I will leave a link to the project repository.

https://github.com/tresor13/calculator/tree/main/server/src

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you didn't mock the `CacheService`, and instead used the real class. In this case, Nest tries to create the instance from the class, but it has some dependencies which are not provided in the provider list.

So you need to either add dependencies of `CacheService` in the provider list or mock the class.

```ts
providers: [
  { useClass: CalculatorService, provide: CALCULATOR_SERVICE },
  {
    useClass: ExpressionCounterService,
    provide: EXPRESSION_COUNTER_SERVICE,
  },
  {
    useClass: RegExCreatorService,
    provide: REGEXP_CREATOR_SERVICE_INTERFACE,
  },
  { useClass: CacheService, provide: CACHE_SERVICE },
  { useClass: HistoryService, provide: HISTORY_SERVICE },
  /* dependencies of CacheService */
],
```

or

```ts
{ useValue: mockedCacheService, provide: CACHE_SERVICE }
```

The `mockCacheService` is just a simple object, which every method is mocked by `jest.fn()`:

```
const mockedCacheService = {
  /* f1 is just a sample method in the CacheService class*/
  f1: jest.fn(),
  /* other methods */
};
```

> The useValue syntax is useful for injecting a constant value, putting an external library into the Nest container, or replacing a real implementation with a **mock** object. Let's say you'd like to force Nest to use a mock CatsService for testing purposes.

Comment: ```CacheService``` has dependencies with ```CalculatorService``` which is already included to providers. And also ```@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache``` but how to provide this dependency to provider I don't know. I guess the best decision is to make a mock. But cannot find good tutorial for this.

Comment: You didn't share the `CacheService` code, and I don't know what this class looks like. However, I've edited my answer and shown you a snippet of how to mock the methods of a class. Although there are many ways to mock a class. You may need to read [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions) or [this one](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks)